# Проблема с create patch в tortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

Я пытаюсь создать патч в TortoiseSVN, но я не могу зафиксировать удаленные файлы,то есть при выполнении команды create patch в патче отображаются только удалённые файлы, в итоге в патче появляются только те, которые были добавлены или изменены. Помогите решить проблему. Патч делаю нажатием правой кнопки мыши в папке с проектом и выбором команды create patch.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблемы была в intellij IDEA, плагин SVN работал не правильно и не фиксировал удаления файлов. Если удалять через SVN (правая кнопка мыши-> delete) то все отобразится в патче. Вывод: пофиксить плагин SVN для intellij IDEA.